# I want to charge different fees for different strings

Tags: solidity

For example, there are two strings named Category1 and Category2.
The minimum fee for sending messages under these categories is 1 Ethereum.

When I send a message for Category 1, it charges me the minimum fee of 1 Ethereum. The person who wants to send a new message for category 1 has to pay more than I paid.

This should work independently for each category.

I've been working on it for a while, but I couldn't find a solution.

My codes are below

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <=0.9.0;

contract MFC {
    address payable owner;
    uint public minPrice = 1 ether;
    uint public cur_Price;
    uint public category_Price;
    string public categoryName;
    uint public curPrice1 = 1;
    uint public curPrice2 = 2; 
    
    constructor () {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }    

    event AddMessage        (address recipient, uint messageId);
    event DeleteMessage     (uint tweetId, bool isDeleted);

    struct Message {
        uint id;
        address username;
        string categoryName;
        string messageText;
        bool isDeleted;
        uint curPrice;
        uint categoryPrice;
    } 

    Message[] public messages;

    mapping(uint256 => Message) messageToOwner;
    mapping(string => uint) cPr;
    

    function getCpr (string memory category) public view returns (uint) {
        return cPr[category];
    }

    function addMessage(string memory _categoryName, string memory _messageText, bool _isDeleted) external payable {
        
        cur_Price = msg.value;
        categoryName = _categoryName;
        uint messageId = messages.length;


if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_categoryName)) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked(categoryName))) {
    require(msg.value == curPrice1);
    curPrice1 = curPrice1 * 2;
} else if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_categoryName)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(categoryName))){
    require(msg.value == curPrice2);
    curPrice2 = curPrice2 * 3;
}
          
        messages.push(
            Message({
                id : messageId, 
                username : msg.sender, 
                categoryName : _categoryName, 
                messageText : _messageText, 
                isDeleted : _isDeleted, 
                curPrice : cur_Price,
                categoryPrice : msg.value
                })
        );




        emit AddMessage(msg.sender, messageId);

    }

    function getInfo(uint _messageId) public view returns (Message memory) {
        require(_messageId < messages.length);
        return messages[_messageId];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make cur_price for each category

```
if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_categoryName)) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked(categoryName))) {
    require(msg.value == curPrice1);
    curPrice1 = curPrice1 * 2;
} else if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_categoryName)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(categoryName))){
    require(msg.value == curPrice2);
    curPrice2 = curPrice2 * 3;
}
```

**After Edit**

Change to:

```
uint public curPrice1 = 1 ether;
uint public curPrice2 = 2 ether;
```

Now make sure you send **exactly** the price. Also, notice that the amounts grows in the code I published for you, curPrice1 first equals 1 ether, than 2 ether, than 4 ether....

Comment: Thank you but Could you write more clearly? I'm still in the learning phase, I'm not a master.

Comment: @MuratIlgım this forum is here to help, tell me if this code example relevant to you

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  I'll try the code when I get to my PC.  I will post the result here. Thank you very much again for your help.

Comment: There is some error


from solidity:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "cur_Price"?
  --> contracts/mfc.sol:47:26:
   |
47 |     require(msg.value == curPrice1);
   | 


from solidity:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "cur_Price"?
  --> contracts/mfc.sol:48:5:
   |
48 |     curPrice1 = curPrice1 * 2;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^

from solidity:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "cur_Price"?
  --> contracts/mfc.sol:48:17:
   |
48 |     curPrice1 = curPrice1 * 2;
   |

Comment: from solidity:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "cur_Price"?
  --> contracts/mfc.sol:50:26:
   |
50 |     require(msg.value == curPrice2);
   |   


from solidity:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "cur_Price"?
  --> contracts/mfc.sol:51:5:
   |
51 |     curPrice2 = curPrice2 * 3;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^

from solidity:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "cur_Price"?
  --> contracts/mfc.sol:51:17:
   |
51 |     curPrice2 = curPrice2 * 3;
   |

Comment: @MuratIlgım first define in the contract curPrice1, curPrice2 and set it to be the initial value

Comment: Should the definition be in a struct?  Or at the beginning of the contract?

Comment: The contract probably

Comment: Yes, I defined it. No error. But when I try to add a message it gives an error.

contract MFC {
    address payable owner;
    uint public minPrice = 1 ether;
    uint public cur_Price;
    uint public category_Price;
    string public categoryName;
    uint public curPrice1 = 1;
    uint public curPrice2 = 2; 
    
    constructor () {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

Comment: [vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: MFC.addMessage(string,string,bool) 0xb31...4E9CAvalue: 4000000000000000000 weidata: 0x87b...00000logs: 0hash: 0x608...5a45d
transact to MFC.addMessage errored: VM error: revert.

revert
 The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: Can you try the entire contract in remix please?

Comment: Pls post the new contract in your question

Comment: I edited main question.

Comment: @Fishman try now

Comment: I tried the code in my main question.  The remix shows no errors.  There is a green tick.  But when I want to send a message, it gives a transaction error.

Comment: You need to send one ether to the contract or two

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. By the way, thank you for answering my endless questions. :)

Comment: Well, I'm missing details. pls approve my answer if it helped for the specific question. try asking another more specific question with all the details :)

Comment: Ok.I already approved your question. Thank you again.